# DynamoDB Items read/second

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

A colleague of mine suggested DynamoDB and I am quite excited. But I am a bit confused by the AWS cost calculator. Prices are growing fast when increasing the "items read/second" property. The default is 25. What exactly does that mean?

In my application I am building a search index myself, so I have to fetch all data. Lets say I have 25 item reads per second, does that mean I have to wait 40 seconds until all the data have arrived for a set of 1000 records in a collection/table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the items are less than 1KB in size each, yes, you'd have to wait ~40 seconds.

Comment: Keep in mind that the 25 reads per second is mainly intended for evaluation purposes and not really for production use. 50 reads per second of throughput is only about $5.25 a month, so increasing the throughput shouldn't be to hard.

Comment: Yeah but that doesn't really make it better. The search index has to be rebuild if something changes, even if it takes 20 seconds that means that other queries on that table would have to wait 20 seconds. That's a blocker sadly. Tuning it up to 1000 items almost costs 100 bucks. For that I can run a hell of a mongo cluster.